# How to find out what is represented by the intermediate value used in SQL Server execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

I'm learning how to read the actual execution plan in SQL Server. I have noticed that SQL Server tends to represent intermediate value used in the physical query plan as e.g. `expr1006`, `expr1007` etc. (i.e. `expr` followed by a number).

Here is a screenshot. Notice near the bottom, the expressions `expr1006, expr1008, expr1009` listed in the section `output list`.

[image]

It it possible to find out what they really represent?

Comment: In addition to Martin Smith's answer below, there is a third party tool called SQL Sentry Plan Explorer (free download) which you can use to analyse your execution plans, there is a tab in it where you can view all the expressions used in the plan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click the compute scalar and choose "properties".

Look in the "Defined Values" section.

You will see something like `expr1006 = SomeExpression()` if `expr1006` is computed there. There may be multiple expressions defined.

[image]

Otherwise follow the tree down towards the leaves to find the first place that `expr1006` appears and look at the properties of that operator.

For large plans viewing as XML and searching for `expr1006` is the quickest way to see where the expression is defined. This is also sometimes required even for small plans as for some constructs the `DefinedValue` contains a `ValueVector` rather than a `ColumnReference` and these don't show up in the SSMS UI. You need to go digging into the plan XML to see that the expressions are output from internal function `GetRangeWithMismatchedTypes` for example.

The above is usually enough. In some builds of SQL Server it was also possible to actually see the values of these expressions by using the `query_trace_column_values` extended event. [More information about that here](http://www.queryprocessor.com/query-trace-column-values/).